# How to align Series on Kendo UI line chart?

Tags: charts, telerik, kendo-ui, kendo-dataviz

I need to align the series lines to the right of the chart. It is always centered. How I can do it?

Comment: I have been looking for a property that help me with. But I just found properties for label aligment but not for chart lines alignment. I need something like tje justified property of the CategoryAxis that help me to align to the right...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Q3 version of the Chart supports a [justified](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/dataviz/chart#categoryaxisjustified%20booleandefault) setting for each axis. It stretches line and area series to the very end of the axis.

```
categoryAxis: {
  justified: true
}
```

See a live demo here: [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/ihaqov/1/edit)

I hope I understood your question correctly.

Comment: Thank you for your Quick Response, I like justified too, but I would like to align to the right. So When I set 2 values in the datasource I would like it to show 2 points of the line chart but aligned to the right.

I did it in silverlight using the live data sample of the telerik charts. When I start adding point to the serie It starts displaying on the chart from the right to the left. and it is not justified. Can I do the same thing with KendoUi charts?

Comment: The demo you refer to uses a date axis and the alignment is done by setting the axis range. I suppose you can do the same with the date axis of the Kendo Chart. See http://demos.kendoui.com/dataviz/line-charts/date-axis.html and http://docs.kendoui.com/api/dataviz/chart#categoryaxismin-object